# Why does Powershell Get-Package not list some packages when running as SYSTEM on Windows 10?

Tags: powershell

I have a Windows 10 Scheduled Task set with the following, "When running the task, use the following user account: SYSTEM". The trigger is "At log on" and the action is the following,

```
PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\test\test.ps1
```

The following is "test.ps1"

```
Get-Package | Out-File c:\test\packages.txt
```

The "packages.txt" file shows 576 packages. If I run the same Get-Package code in Powershell, it returns 579 packages, 3 additional packages. One of the three missing packages is a program called [Flameshot](https://flameshot.org/).

Why isn't Get-Package able to see Flameshot when running as SYSTEM?

Is there an alternative way to see installed programs that can be run as SYSTEM and will show programs like Flameshot?

Comment: Can you narrow down the issue a little by trying the following:

Is it just an issue when running on logon? does it do the same when you just manually run the scheduled task.

Is it anything to do with the output to file, if you manually run: `Get-Package | Out-File c:\test\packages.txt` in powershell directly does it show Flameshot?

Is it just System when run via task scheduler, or does it work fine if you run the script as system via psexec.exe -i -s powershell_ise.exe. (You can download psexec from Microsoft)

Comment: I believe I found the answer, but not sure if I'm correct. Some programs give the option of being installed just for a single user or all users. Flameshot seems to install only to a user by default, no options. When running Get-Package as SYSTEM, it's not there, but running it under an account with it installed it shows because it's installed under just that account. Never came across something like this before.

Comment: Surprising that the Get-Package with run with admin rights doesn't show user installs. Although that said I don't know of a way to install or uninstall apps that are per user without impersonating the user, so maybe its just assumed that if you want per user apps, then you should do while impersonating the user, since you can't do anything like install or uninstall without the impersonation.